# Open NFC target doesn't appear on the AVD Manager

Tags: nfc

I've installed the Open NFC add-on by following the manual from the zip file I had downloaded from http://open-nfc.org/wp/home/downloads. The Open NFC add-on appeared on the SDK Manager and was installed but then when I'm about to create a new AVD, it doesn't appear on the Target. Can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: In my experience, the NFC support of the NFC simulator is rather basic and it crashes often when used in combination with the AVD, after which you have to restart your AVD. This makes the whole set-up of limited use, IMO. I would suggest you get a real Android device with NFC built in.

Answer (score 0):

just create a avd but dont open it..

now open connection center and NFc simulator after that run the avd then it works